# javascript working fine in localhost but not on live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a comment system in php,ajax and javascript this code used to work fine in localhost but when i transfered my website to live server it does not work idk why 
this is my script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $post = $(this);
    var username2 = $(this).parent().find("#username").val();
    var comment2 = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val();

    $commentsec = $(this).closest("form").next(".comments");

    //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
    var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
        comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };
   //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 



    $.ajax({
   url:'comments.php',  
   data:dataString,
   success:function(){
$commentsec.append('<p class="written"><a href="users.php?id= <?php echo $id3; ?>"><b style=color:black !important>'+username2+'</b> </a>'+comment2+"</p>"+'<div class="dropdown"><img src="images/ellipsis.png" class="dots"><div class="dropdown-content"><br><p  class="delete" data-delete=<?php echo $commentid; ?>">delete</p></div></div>');
     $(" #comment").val("");     
   }
   });
});
```

is there any way i can get error in my error log??

this is my network tab 
[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFzTf.png)

[console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBVBs.png)

Comment: Open developers console and check errors.

Comment: what is the error.... provide the error here, and we'll try to figure it out.

Comment: no error regarding this issue

Comment: so, if no error, what is the problem actually?

Comment: when i click the comment button it just tells me that the button is clicked and if i click it again and again it tells me how many time button have been clicked

Comment: nothing happens neither the data goes into database nor the comment appends in comment section @SyamsoulAzrien

Comment: you said no error. but from what i see in your SS, there's a lot of errors... try open `console` tab and give us screenshot

Comment: done @SyamsoulAzrien

Comment: Did you use jquery.js on your console it's says jquery.min.js error

Comment: yes i use jquery.min.js @MD.JubairMizan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. open `Developer Tools`
2. Go to `Network` tab

[image]

try to look for `'comments.php'`... If `'comments.php'` appears in `red` text, it means the url you provide is returning ERROR (or the URL is invalid)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185136/discussion-on-answer-by-syamsoul-azrien-javascript-working-fine-in-localhost-but).

Answer (score 0):

For you php error check

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You can check any kind of your javascript error by inspect your browser and go to your console and debug with console.log

**Hope this will help you**